# How to click image in a table in selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

On the Web page, I have 3 buttons with a link image in a table.I want to click on Image. But I could not locate the image with button as "send"

Here is HTML code for image embeded in table:

```
<a class="ctl00_C_S_Z_ctrlActionToolbar_Menu1_1" href="javascript: ValidateSendMessage()>
<img src="ShmControls/ShmImages/SHM_Send_Trans.png" alt="Send Message" style="border-style:none;vertical-align:middle;>"Send" /a>
```

Let me know, how I can locate this button on the web page?

I tried with all the below options to locate image element

```
IWebElement Send = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("a[@href= 'javascript: ValidateSendMessage()')]"));
IWebElement Send = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//img[contains(src,'ShmControls/ShmImages/SHM_Send_Trans.png')]"));
IWebElement Send = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*@id='ctl00_C_S_Z_ctrlActionToolbar_Menu1']"));        
IWebElement Send = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("ShmControls/ShmImages/SHM_Send_Trans.png"));
```

Answer (score 0):

To click on the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) with text as **Send** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *CssSelector*:

  ```
  IWebElement Send = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a[class*='ctrlActionToolbar_Menu'][href*='ValidateSendMessage']"));
  ```
- Using *XPath*:

  ```
  IWebElement Send = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(@class, 'ctrlActionToolbar_Menu') and contains(@href, 'ValidateSendMessage')]"));
  ```